# Palindrome problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, palindrome

> Let $F (n, k)$ be the number of length $n$ strings that can be formed using $k$ discrete digits. Let $G (n, k)$ be the number of length $n$ palindromic strings that can be formed using $k$ discrete digits. Find $G (21, 7)-G (20, 7)$
>
> Options:
> $f (10, 7)$, $f (20, 7)$, $f (10, 6)$, $f(21,7)$
> Please note that options have some constant multiplied with them (which I don't remember now. So any answer which has these options multiplied with some constant would be correct

So, I tried to solve this in the following way. For G(21,7). We have to find palindromic strings from 7 distinct digits. Since length of palindrome is 21. There will be 11 unique digits (not necessarily distinct). So for each digit we have 7 choices. So 7^11 are the total number of such palindromes. Similarly for G(20,7) 7^10 will be the possible palindromes. However on subtracting the two I am not able to get the answer. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does "$k$ discrete digits" mean? Also, please edit your question to show what you've tried and where you got stuck (just below the now-block quoted problem statement).

Comment: sure. will do that

Comment: so k distinct characters. This is what I take it to be. I recently saw this question in a finance company test.

Comment: I would probably go for "$k$ digits", because a non-trivial palindrome has to have repeated digits. Anyway, your question has become far more likely to attract an answer now.

Comment: Maybe. I see you have another interpretation. The "discrete/distinct digits" thing is most ambiguous.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 7^11 and 7^10?

Comment: yeah, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: I have never encountered indiscrete digits, although "indiscreet digits" might evoke the image of groping fingers. Also I think that occurrences of $F$/$f$ are meant to be either all upper-case or all lower-case, but not mixed as in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**G(21,7)**

That means 21-digit palindromic number.
In order to form this number you use:

{a 10-digit number,let's say A}{any number from 0 to k-1}{the number A inverted, =one possible option}

so the possible combinations are F(10,7)*7*1

**G(20,7)**

That means 20-digit palindromic number.
In order to form this number you use:

{a 10-digit number,let's say A}{the number A inverted, =one possible option}

so the possible combinations are F(10,7)*1

So:

$G(21,7)-G(20,7)=7*f(10,7)-F(10,7)=6*F(10,7)$

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a plausible explanation. Thanks. Would love to know if you've seen this problem somewhere before.

Comment: No, not the same. but i've solved many problems with palindromic numbers in project euler